# Import Script Into Every Website The User Visits. (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I was wondering if I could inject an external js file into every website a user visits with a chrome extension. I am very new to this so I haven't tried so far I just need the manifest file background.js and other things required. I also want the script to load before everything else on the page.

Comment: Have you looked into content scripts? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: I would like to use an external script. Injected into every website. with the src element in html.